# Writing a Text to Speech file as an MP3 - IBM Watson

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-watson, watson-text-to-speech

I'm following the [documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/text-to-speech?code=node#synthesize-request) for the `Node.JS` implementation of the IBM Watson Text-to-Speech API.

I want to output the resultant file into `MP3` format. The documentation recommends augmenting the base code but I'm not sure how to do that. My code is rendering unplayable `MP3`s.

Here is what it says in the documentation:

```
textToSpeech.synthesize(synthesizeParams)
  .then(response => {

    // The following line is necessary only for
    // wav formats; otherwise, `response.result`
    // can be directly piped to a file.

    return textToSpeech.repairWavHeaderStream(response.result);
  })
  .then(buffer => {
    fs.writeFileSync('hello_world.wav', buffer);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('error:', err);
  });
```

As it says, `response.result` should be directly piped to a file. This is one of my many attempts (that renders an error).

```
textToSpeech
  .synthesize(synthesizeParams)  
  .then(response => {
    fs.writeFileSync('Hello.mp3', response.result)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('error:', err)
  })
```

How can I output the text-to-speech input as an `MP3`?

Answer (score 0):

Provided your params are requesting an mp3 file, this will be the `accept` parameter, then your code looks ok. So if the output file isn't being recognised as an audio, then it is most likely a text file containing an error message. This error message will indicate what is wrong, which most likely will be an unauthorised message.

I take it that your catch error block isn't logging anything.